# Plurality of verb depending on plurality of list elements

Tags: subject-verb-agreement, singular-vs-plural, lists

**This question is also open on EL&U:**
[“There Is”/“There are” depends on plurality of the first list element or not?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140854/there-is-there-are-depends-on-plurality-of-the-first-list-element-or-not)

*Considering the amount of controversy it aroused, I believe it's past "Learners'" level.*

---

An edit was suggested to my sentence.

> There <strike>was</strike> *were* an orange, some grapes, two apples and a small pile of cherries on the plate.

In my native language plurality of the verb always follows plurality of the first element on the list. *There were an orange,...* sounds awkward to me, no matter what follows up. My simple solution was reordering:

> There were some grapes, an orange, two apples and a small pile of cherries on the plate.

But that's not the first time I faced this situation and I'd like to know what the rules of grammar say about that — was my editor overzealous or am I trying to copy rules of my language that don't apply in English?

Comment: See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59808/mixing-plural-and-singular-list-items-with-a-single-verb — ELU agrees with you.

Comment: I don't think that question is the same. Here we are talking about a compound noun. There it is talking about several independent sentences turned into clauses and combined into a single sentence by elision. Consider "There are a dog and a cat on the roof." Clearly plural "are" is called for. But "There is a dog on the roof and a cat in the window." Now we use the singular "is" because it is no longer a compound subject but two separate subjects of two separate clauses.

Comment: @Gilles The example you've pointed to is different than this one. It's using *or* instead of *and*, which makes it completely different. At least that's what the answer with the most votes is suggesting, which I'd be inclined to agree with.

Comment: @JohnQPublic I should have said [Pitarou's answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/59808/mixing-plural-and-singular-list-items-with-a-single-verb/59839#59839), which also recommends agreement to the nearest element of the enumeration for “there is/are X and Y”.

Comment: I just find this. [Oddness When You Start a Sentence with "There Is"](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/oddness-when-you-start-a-sentence-with-there-is)

Comment: @243 Grammar Girl's analysis is one way to look at it, but I don't think it correctly accounts for how the construction is used in all contexts, which is probably why modern grammars usually don't look at it that way.

Comment: Having looked this up in another grammar, I report Quark et al.'s analysis: *there* is again considered the subject (as in every grammar I've checked), although they suggest that *there* might be considered the **grammatical subject**, while the other thingy might be called a **notional subject**.  (Huddleston & Pullum call the other thingy a **displaced subject**, although they note that a displaced subject "is not a kind of subject".)

Comment: @snailboat From a linguistic standpoint, *there* is in the subject position, but from a grammatical point of view, existential clauses aren't the actual subject. *There* isn't the agent of action (the action in this case being *to exist*). It's difficult to explain because there is no action in a sentence using a linking verb only.

Comment: I take "subject" as a syntactic role and "agent" as a semantic role.  There is often a close relationship between syntactic role and semantic role, but these relationships don't hold in all cases.

Comment: @snailboat I believe that we're both saying the same thing, or at least I don't think anything you've said thus far is wrong. This would be one of those cases where *the relationship between the two doesn't hold*.

Comment: I am voting to close because this question has an exact duplicate on EL&U, and new answers should be posted on only one site or the other.  Closing the question will prevent new answers from being posted here, fulfilling that requirement.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

### *Were* is absolutely correct here. The reason that it's *were* and **not** *was* is that it's a compound subject (which is indicated by *and*).

Your editor has got a sharp eye. It's definitely awkward, but it's technically correct, which is why you should, as you've suggested, simply re-write the sentence so that the singular item is **not** the first item in the list (this obviously won't work though if you have all singular items in your list, which I'll explain in a bit).

English grammar does not dictate--to this native speaker's recollection--that the first item in a list indicates the grammatical number. I will say, however, that *there were an orange, grapes, two apples ...* sounds awful to my ear (and I suspect that this is true with most speakers).

I also think that most speakers make this error without realizing it with **[expletive](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/572/04/) [constructions](http://www.uhv.edu/ac/newsletters/writing/grammartip2005.12.06.htm)** (i.e. sentences that are constructed in the order of *there/it + be + subject*, rather than the more common, active voice, *Subject-Verb-Object* order). It's generally best to avoid expletive constructions whenever possible (it's not always possible to do so, but in your example, *there* is unnecessary)

The indefinite article *an* is ordinarily a marker of singularity, which makes it sound as if it should be *was*, but with compound subject, that's not the case. It still would be *were* even if it were**: *There were an orange, grapes, an apple, and a cherry [**ALL**] piled on the plate.* Or, even better: *An orange, grapes, two apples, and a small pile of cherries **were** all on the plate.*

If the sentence were**, *There **was** an orange*, and nothing more, than *was* would be correct. But because you're talking about multiple subjects that are/were grouped together, the subject is plural.

There are four objects in this list--that's counting the grapes and cherries each as a single unit; technically, there are more--so there's no question that it's plural. This isn't a one-or-the-other situation; it's collective.

A general rule of thumb would be that when you're using *and* as a conjunction, it's a compound/plural subject, and thus indicating a plural form of the verb. If instead you're using *or*, then it's singular, regardless of the article.

**I'm using *were* in two of the above sentences with a singular subjects because I'm using the subjunctive mood; otherwise it'd be *was*. That's the only time it's ever correct to use *were* with a singular subject.

---

From Garner's *Modern American English Usage*, 3rd Ed.:

> Language-Change Index
>
> - *there is* (or *there's*) with a compound subject whose first member is singular <there's an outhouse and a sump pump out back>: Stage 4

Key to the Language-Change Index:

> Stage 4: The form becomes virtually universal but is opposed on cogent
> grounds by a few linguistic stalwarts (die-hard snoots).

Garner's Stage 4 Analogies:

> School-Grade Analogy: Grade B
>
> Golf Analogy: Bogey
>
> Olfaction Analogy: Vaguely odorous
>
> Skill-Level Analogy: Amateur
>
> Military Analogy: General discharge
>
> Etiquette Analogy: Elbows on table
>
> Traffic-Penalty Analogy: Warning ticket
>
> School-Discipline Analogy: 1-hour detention
>
> Moral Analogy: Peccadillo
>
> Parliamentary-Discipline Analogy: Warning

As you can see, this is not quite standard yet, but Garner notes that using *there* with a compound subject is widespread nevertheless. He notes that purists still object to it, and to my interpretation, that it's technically incorrect. Therefore, while it'd be perfectly acceptable in speech, it shouldn't be used that way formally. Very careful speakers/writer's will object to this usage in writing.

---

Diana Hacker And Nancy Sommers also indicate that singular compound subjects take plural verbs in expletive constructions in *Rules for Writers*. They agree that in sentences beginning with *there be*--i.e., when the subject follows the verb in a declarative statement--**the subject is plural** if it's a compound subject, **even if the first item in the list is singular**, and therefore, it's got to take a **plural verb**

From *Rules for Writers*, 7th Ed.:

> **21g Make the verb agree with its subject, even when the subject follows the verb.**
>
> Sentences beginning with *there is* or *there are* (or *there was* or
> *there were*) are inverted; the subject follows the verb.
>
> *There <del>was</del> **were** a social worker and a neighbor at the meeting.*
>
> The subject, *worker and neighbor*, is plural, so the verb that
> follows must be *were*
>
> Occasionally you may decide to invert a sentence for a variety of
> effect. When you do so, check to make sure that your subject and verb
> agree.
>
> *Of particular concern <del>is</del> **are** penicillin and
> tetracycline, antibiotics.*
>
> The subject, *penicillin and tetracycline*, is plural, so the verb
> must be *are*.

---

From *The Chicago Manual of Style Online*, 16th Ed.:

> 5.32Exceptions regarding pronoun number
>
> There are several refinements to the rules stated just above: (1) When
> two or more singular antecedents denote the same thing and are
> connected by and, the pronoun referring to the antecedents is singular
> {a lawyer and role model received her richly deserved recognition
> today}. (2) When two or more singular antecedents are connected by and
> and modified by each, every, or no, the pronoun referring to the
> antecedents is singular {every college and every university encourages
> its students to succeed}. (3) When two or more singular antecedents
> are connected by or, nor, either–or, or neither–nor, they are treated
> separately and referred to by a singular pronoun {neither the orange
> nor the peach smells as sweet as it should}. **(4)** When two or more
> antecedents of different numbers are connected by ***or*** or ***nor***, the
> **pronoun’s number agrees with that of the nearest (usually the last)
> antecedent**; if possible, cast the sentence so that the plural
> antecedent comes last {neither the singer nor the dancers have asked
> for their paychecks}. **(5)** When two or more antecedents of different
> numbers are connected by ***and***, **they are usually referred to by a plural
> pronoun regardless of the nouns’ order** {the horses and the mule kicked
> over their water trough}. (emphasis added)

Comment: There is a time and a place for plurals, and I'm not convinced this is one.

Comment: "most speakers make this error" is a linguistic oxymoron. What most speakers do is, by definition, not the error.

Comment: @Gilles And note: It's not "there **are** a time and place for plurals, damn it!" :)

Comment: @Kaz I did misspeak, but *what most speakers do/say* is **most certainly not** standard English. That's what **most native** speakers would say. I should not have qualified my answer by including both. Also, there's a key difference in the example of ***there is a time and a place*** and the asker's example in that *time and place* are both sharing a common article. **There is *a* time and *a* place for plurals.** In that case you could say that it was a reduction, but not in the case of a list of ***both*** singular ***and*** plural items.

Comment: Are you both suggesting that *An orange, grapes, two apples, and a small pile of cherries **was** all on the plate.* is correct? It's definitely not correct if so.

Comment: @JohnQPublic “*An orange and two apples is on the plate” is definitely incorrect. I do not think the same can be said for the different construction “There <be> an orange and two apples on the plate”. I'm not a native speaker, so I can't speak conclusively, but I find “there are an orange and two apples on the plate” jarring. I'm perfectly aware of the semantic number, and my native language would force a plural in any similar construction, but English sometimes admit agreement-with-nearest, and I think this is a case of it.

Comment: @JohnQPublic That sentence does not use the "there + be" construction.

Comment: @Kaz it **is certainly** *there + be* as *was/were* is a form of *to be*. ***There is/are/was/were  = there + be***. And yes, I understand that *there* is a *placeholder*. I pointed out that the expletive construction is what's probably leading to the confusion. When you rearrange the words, without changing anything else, in active voice, it can **only** be ***were***.

Comment: +1, I agree with you @JohnQPublic, it's definitely a _were_ - a lot of fruits _were_ there, there _were_ a lot of fruits. It's a common **mistake** to use _was_ on sentences like these.

Comment: @AdamGeraldy “There were a lot of fruit”: sure, because “a lot of fruit” is plural. This has no bearing on whether *be* should agree with the whole complement or with the first element of the enumeration in “there <be> X and Y”.

Comment: @Gilles You clearly have the best intentions, but you are misguided here. The subject is, in fact, *a lot of fruit*, whether you list them separately or not. You're being completely thrown off by *there*. There has absolutely no function in the sentence. It could be replaced with any noun. *Hey Bob: an orange, some grapes, two apples, and a small pile of cherries were on the plate.* That's how there is functioning. What you're missing is that 3 of the four items in the subject are plural (grapes can be singular if referring to a bunch, but not with some). This is basic subject-verb agreement.

Comment: @Gilles both Kaz and I have pointed out that *there* has nothing to do with anything.

Comment: @JohnQPublic I know about subject-verb agreement. You haven't explained why it would apply here. “There is” is actually analyzed as having a dummy subject *there*. Even if you posit that the dummy subject has to take the number of the logical subject, does this still apply to “there <be> an apple and two oranges”? If something “sounds awful”, it may need to be classified as an exception to the general rule. Grammar is a codification of usage.

Comment: @Gilles I'm not being condescending. I'm sorry, but if you think *there* is in fact a dummy subject, then you simply do not understand this construction. The subject in English must always agree with the verb, no matter what. It's the only widely accepted rule of English grammar. It sounds awful, but the *exception to the rule* is that it must be revised. Are you telling me that you prefer, *There **was** two oranges and an apple?* Rearranging the subjects does not change their number. You can only reduce to the singular verb when **all** items are singular, and then it's just a reduction.

Comment: Kaz was correct in stating that sometimes *there was a cat and there was a dog,* is reduced to *there's a cat and a dog*; that doesn't make it proper grammar to do so. I make this mistake myself too.

Comment: @JohnQPublic The word *there* in “there is/are/…” *is* classified as a dummy subject by some grammarians. It's how it's analyzed in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There_is#There_as_pronoun), for example. While the logical subject may have been considered the postponed grammatical subject in some ancestor language of English, this is not the only (or mainstream, I think) way to analyze modern English. “*There was two oranges and an apple” is of course different since the nearest element of the enumeration is plural: both rules require a plural verb.

Comment: @Gilles I understand exactly what you mean by *dummy subject*; I am, however, hesitant to refer to *there* as a *subject* with English language *learners*. It's an *existential clause*, and *there is/are/was/were* simply means *Hey, this is there*. This quote is from your Wikipedia link: *In colloquial English, however, the contraction there's is often used where there are would be expected.* And this is exactly what happens in speech. People tend to use the contracted *there's* because it flows naturally, but in **edited writing** it's not appropriate.

Comment: Huddleston & Pullum agree with Gilles and analyze dummy *there* as subject. Why? Because it appears in subject position and it undergoes subject-auxiliary inversion. How can you explain subject-verb agreement, then? By calling dummy *there* a pronoun which takes on the number of the logical subject, much like the relative pronouns *which* or *who* take on the number of their antecedents. (Its appearance in tag questions also shows that it's a pronoun.)  The construction with *there's* is not ungrammatical, it's informal; it's also evidence that agreement is actually with *there*.

Comment: @snailboat There is a reason why I'm being so emphatic about this: this question was about edited, professional writing. I suppose I'm trying to make clear that *there [be]* is a special construction. I don't have a problem with the informal use of *there's*, and in fact, I've been known to use it myself. But native speakers take many liberties in speech. I do take issue with the non-contracted *there is/was* though, even in speech.

Comment: I found a good quote here, http://grammar.about.com/od/c/g/comsubjecterm.htm. --"An odd quirk that proves nothing aside from the fact that some rules do have exceptions." (Theodore Bernstein, Miss Thistlebottom's Hobgoblins, 1971).

Comment: -1 for posting an incredibly long image of text, of which the relevant section comprises perhaps three sentences, ***without*** a cogent summary of the relevant section.

Comment: Thank you for the citation. Your summary disagrees with the text you cite. Your judgement puts the construction at stage 3 or a little before in Garner's terms, whereas he classifies it as stage 4, where it's acceptable for formal use. (Cc @PeterShor)

Comment: Thanks for fixing that … the answer's readability is greatly improved.

Comment: @Gilles Re: My summary (read: widespread=ubiquitous; ***very careful*** and ***purists*** =stalwarts; and ***cogent=relevant***). The edit has removed all of Garner's analogies. I'm going to edit the answer again to include them, because they are relevant to my synopsis.

Comment: @PeterShor Sorry for posting the three images, but there was relevant text on all three of those pages. And **I did provide a cogent summary** directly below them. You're free to disagree with my interpretation of Garner's judgment, but my synopsis was far from irrelevant. I was trying to not only save time, but also to include **all** relevant information on both this construction and Garner's assessment.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I never assumed that you downvoted me. One of those downvotes was actually an upvote that was just changed today. This is in no way personal, and I'm in no way angry with you. The downvotes to my answer have nothing to do with you; but even if they were related to you, you're entitled to your opinion.

Comment: @Mari-LouA From my profile: *-12  5 hours ago  2 events   Plurality of verb depending on plurality of list elements
-2  5 hours ago  downvote   
-10  5 hours ago  **unupvote*** I don't mind being downvoted, but it's more helpful when people leave comments as to why they've done so (I know who two of those are -- I don't know who reversed their vote, but it's not important to me). I enjoy debate, this isn't, as I said previously, personal. And I'm far from perfect; I do make mistakes and can admit when I'm wrong. I also **did not** downvote your answer out of vindictiveness.

Comment: "There is a time and a place" is an interesting counter-example. But I'd say that's different from "an orange and two apples" because "time and place" is really identifying a single thing. I struggle with this one, but I think it's a little like saying "There is a brown and black dog." I use the singular "is" because there's only one dog, regardless of the number of colors. But granted, in the "time and place" case I'd have to claim there's some unstated noun that is the "real" subject. I think it's a tough case.

Answer (score 12):

I would like to add this interesting information, which is highly related to this question, and even more suitable for ELTs and ELLs.

This following was taken from the article: Joybrato Mukherjee (2006): "[Corpus linguistics and language pedagogy: the state of the art - and beyond](http://www.uni-giessen.de/anglistik/ling/Staff/mukherjee/pdfs/Mukherjee-2006b.pdf)", Corpus Technology and Language Pedagogy: New Resources, New Tools, New Methods, eds. Sabine Braun, Kurt Kohn & Joybrato Mukherjee. Frankfurt am Main: Peter Lang, 5-24. 337-354.

> Here language specialists with access to a wide range of large corpora of English (including the Bank of English, the BNC and TeleCorpora with Hong Kong English) answer linguistic questions that are put forward by English language
>   teachers. The following two questions refer to the choice of the verb form after
>   coordinated subject noun phrases:
>
> Teacher 4:
>   Hello! Which one is correct?
>   There is a man and a woman outside.
>   Or
>   There are a man and a woman outside.
>   Please give some comments, any one.
>
> Teacher 5:
>   Hi,
>   What should we use in the following sentences? Is or are?
>   1. There ..... an apple and some oranges on the table.
>   2. There ..... some oranges and an apple on the table.
>   Thanks. It seems to me that 'are' is okay in both. Is there any rule here?
>   (Tsui 2004: 50)
>
> These questions exemplify the usefulness of the language corner because very
>   often English language teachers as non-native speakers feel insecure about specific aspects of English usage. The following reply was given by TELEC staff members:
>
> TELEC staff responded to the teachers' questions by pointing out that **usually the singular form of 'be' is used when the first noun that follows is singular and the plural form of 'be' is used when the noun group after it is plural** (see also Collins Cobuild English Grammar, p.416). However, a search through the corpus does show an instance of the following:
>   According to PACE, suspects can only be detained at designated police stations where there are a custody and a reviewing officer.
>   (Tsui 2004: 51)
>
> Apart from the fact that teachers are provided with a general rule of thumb, it is also **highly significant** that the grammatical rule which is also included in **the Collins COBUILD English Grammar does not cover every case**. In fact, the analysis of corpus data reveals that **the scope of virtually all grammatical rules is limited** and that there is a remainder of instances which deviate from the rules.
>   It is very important to make English language teachers fully aware of the fact
>   that with regard to many forms and structures **"the question is not about
>   possibility but about probability of usage"**
>   (Tsui 2004: 51)

(emphasis mine)

Here is the relevant part of the mentioned page in *the Collins COBUILD English Grammar*,

> **verb agreement**
>   **10.50** Usually a plural form to 'be' is used if the noun group after it is plural.
>   *There were two men in the room.*
>
> You use a singular form of 'be' when you are giving a list of items and the first noun in the list is singular or uncountable.
>   *There was a sofa and two chairs.*
>   *There is grief in his face and reproach at the injustice of it all.*
>
> Note that you use a plural form of 'be' in front of plural **quantifiers** beginning with 'a', such as 'a number of', 'a lot of', and 'a few of'.
>   *There were a lot of people camped here.*
>
> You also use a plural form of 'be' in front of numbers beginning with 'a', such as 'a hundred', 'a thousand', and 'a dozen'.
>   *There were a dozen reasons why a man might hurry from a bar.*

which confirms the article. The example *"There **was** a sofa and two chairs."* is the recommended usage for the students, according to the grammar book.

In my opinion, the most important point, at least for English language teachers, is to be fully aware of the fact that with regard to many forms and structures *"the question is not about **possibility** but about **probability** of usage".*

Comment: I'd like to make a few quick points. This is in reference to Hong Kong English, which is a very specific dialect. And I very much dislike this method of teaching English; it's what gives rise to the monstrosity that is *EU English*. Anyway, from your source: *However, a search through the corpus does show an instance of the following: According to PACE, suspects can only be detained at designated police stations where ***there are** a custody and a reviewing officer.* If you want to add a new perspective, that's fine; but I don't see this as being definitive.

Comment: @JohnQPublic It *includes* HK English, but the [Bank of English](http://www.mycobuild.com/about-collins-corpus.aspx) and the [British National Corpus](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/) are certainly not corpora of HK English.

Comment: @snailboat Fair enough. I'd just read the footnotes regarding Hong Kong. I think what I'm trying to make clear is that I welcome new perspectives, but we've got to make a dialectal distinction here, because AmE does not allow this usage formally, and it's unlikely to appear in an edited publication in the US. Perhaps this is not the case for the Commonwealth countries. That's all. And I'm hoping to see some more definitive sources. I actually wouldn't mind being wrong about this question. It'd be interesting to see a wider array of sources since it's still not settled.

Comment: Oh I hadn't realized that you'd offered an additional bounty. I was wondering why this was still so active. Sorry.

Comment: @JohnQPublic I just offered it for fun, and as it happens, it was after DamkerngT posted this answer.  I'm enjoying watching the discussion ;-)  In any case, the same formality distinction is made in AmE and BrE, as far as I'm aware.  The hypothesis put forward by the sociolinguists Meechan & Foley (1994) is that it results from prescriptive influence in schools, and that it runs counter to our natural inclination which appears chiefly in informal registers; they found that greater levels of education are associated with higher levels of concord.

Comment: @JohnQPublic This worries me a little, because it sounds as if I posted this answer because I want the bounty, which I did not and do not. I found that article accidentally last night, while I was looking for some information relevant more to ELT. Having this question kept in one corner of my mind, I noted it down in my private journal, with no strong urge to post. However, earlier today I saw http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140854/there-is-there-are-depends-on-plurality-of-the-first-list-element-or-not at EL&U by SF. So I would like to share what I have, and that's the real reason.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Oh no, not at all. That wasn't directed at you personally. I don't care if you win the bounty. I'm not lording over and protecting my answer. It hadn't noticed the bounty until after my first reply to snailboat. That wasn't meant to question your motives. I was being critical and questioning the definitiveness of your answer in my comment to you directly, but that was it. I'd like to see if anyone can find more sources. I've got shelves full of grammar books that agree with me, so I'm comfortable with saying that for AmE, the plural is proper, and  the singular is colloquial.

Comment: Interestingly, I found [this source](http://www.noslangues-ourlanguages.gc.ca/bien-well/fra-eng/grammaire-grammar/phrases-sentences-eng.html) on Canadian English that states both are correct, but that one is more technically correct than the other. By the way, I'm a grammar geek, and this is fun for me. If I challenge your answer, that means it's thought provoking and that I see room for improvement. Nothing more.

Comment: I'm very glad to hear that from you. Actually, I think based on the article in my post, it's rather clear that TELEC staff's position is to accept both. I was a bit surprised to read that the *Collins COBUILD English Grammar* states the use of singular form so explicitly. Considering that it's one among the most respectable grammar books for ESL learners, it's not surprised to see this confusion, in my opinion. (One good thing, though, is that I can have a good opportunity to open that book after being left dusty on my shelf over a decade perhaps.)

Comment: @DamkerngT. I keep returning to this discussion because oddly most agree that if you change the construction from expletive/existential/inverted to active voice, compound subjects are without question plural. Given the lack of function of *there*, that surprises me. I think that Collins is serving a different purpose: I think they're offering good general advice to non-native speakers that is most often true. I'd cite *Fowler's Modern English Usage* (or even *Stank and White's*), but those are more dated. An ESL grammar book may well disagree with my style guides for practicality.

Comment: @snailboat I just, genuinely, wish that someone could explain why there is a different rule for expletive and active constructions (although I agree that DamkerngT. deserves the bounty). I suspect that you could, but I'll see if someone on ELU is up for the task (without referring back to this).

Answer (score 2):

> 1a) Twenty-five years ago there used to be **two cinemas** in the
> village where I lived.
>
> 1b) Twenty-five years ago **there were two cinemas** in the
> village where I lived.
>
> 2a) Twenty-five years ago there used to be **a nursery**, a primary
> school and a middle school in the village.
>
> 2b) *Twenty-five years ago **there were a nursery**, a primary school and a middle school in the village.
> 2c) Twenty-five years ago **there was a nursery**, a primary school and a middle school in the village.

Sentence 2b) for me is just plain wrong. Just like the OP's example, where an orange, two apples and some grapes *were all* fruit. In 2a) **there were three** different types of schools. (Just now I used a plural verb because I grouped the three institutions together and classified them as schools.) I could have written the following:

> 3a) Twenty-five years ago **there were three schools** in the village where I lived.

In the sentence above, I made a generalisation, the three different types of institutions are indeed schools but in the village where I lived **each one** catered for a different age group. They had a separate identity and were *different* from each other.

In the same vein, one orange is not *two apples* nor *some grapes*; *An orange* is therefore  singular, the verb should agree with its subject. It is considered grammatically incorrect to say and write:  "*There are an orange". Similarly, I would argue, the same logic applies to a list of nouns.

> **There is an** orange, a small pile of cherries and (there are) two apples.

unless you invert the order:

> **There are two** apples, a small pile of cherries and (there is) an orange.

At any rate, back to the schools in an Italian village...

> Twenty five years ago **there was a** nursery school (Preschool), a primary school (Elementary school) and
> a middle school.

In other words, there **was a school** for infants, one for children aged between 6 and 11, and a third one for students aged between 10 and 13. There **was a school for each age group**.

Let's include some illustrations to clarify.

[image]

Nobody is going to disagree with either of these.

[image]

So why is there any difference if I include a list of objects in the singular?

> - There **is** a book, a pen, a pencil, a rubber, and a sharpener on the table.

What if I add a plural noun to that list?

> - There **is** a book, a pen, a rubber, a sharpener **and two pencils** on the table.

Placing the plural noun, two pencils, at the end of the list makes sense. No one is going to believe there is only one object on the table because the verb is singular, but we do know for certain there is *one* book, *one* pen, *one* rubber, etc.

The [website](http://www.towson.edu/ows/moduleSVAGR.htm) where I *borrowed* these images, conveniently avoided the issue of stating whether a list containing singular nouns should have the verb in plural. However, it is worth reading because it does explain subject verb agreement well.

An authoritative source for the bounty offerer might be the BBC.

> [**subject-verb agreement: there is / there are**](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv128.shtml)

The questioner poses this problem to the expert:

> And why then do we say:
>
> There is a chair and a table in this room NOT There are a chair and a
> table in this room?

Roger Woodham replies:

> **there is / there are**
>
> In your example of **there is**, Tanya, it is as if the items are being
> counted separately:
>
> **There’s a** chair and **there’s a** table in the room SO **there’s a** chair and
> table in the room.
>
> But note:
>
> **There are** three chairs and a table in the room.
>
> **There’s a** table and three chairs in the room.
>
> The general rule is that the verb form matches the item(s) that it is
> adjacent to:

- Either the accused or the witnesses **were** lying. They couldn’t both be telling the truth.
- Either the witnesses or the accused **was** lying. They couldn’t both be telling the truth.

> Note that we do not usually begin sentences in English with an
> indefinite noun phrase. We could say:
>
> - A knife and (a) fork **were** on the table.
>
> But we usually don’t. If we want to say that something exists, we
> usually start the sentence with the ‘empty’ grammatical word *there*
> and say:
>
> - **There’s a** knife and (a) fork on the table

I think the BBC and I are in agreement. :)

---

### A second *and* authoritative source

From *Advanced Grammar in Use. A self-study reference book for advanced learners of English* by Martin Hewings, published in 1999 by Cambridge University Press.

Unit 115 page 230 (emphasis not mine)

> If the noun after **be** is singular, the verb is singular; if the
> noun is plural, the verb is plural:

> - **There is** a very good **reason** for my decision.
> - **There were** too many **people** trying to get into the football stadium.

> However, in informal speech we sometimes use **there is**
> before a plural noun:

> - 'Anything to eat?' 'Well, **there's** some apples on the table.'

> If the noun phrase consists of two or more nouns in a list, we use a
> singular verb if the first noun is singular or uncountable, and a
> plural verb if the first noun is plural:

> - When I opened the fridge **there was** only *a bottle of milk*, some eggs, and butter.
> - When I opened the fridge **there were** *some eggs*, a bottle of milk, and butter

.

Answer (score 1):

Your editor is not right.

The reason is that in the "there were" construction, we can regard the items on the plate to be independently there of each other.

That is to say, the sentence is a condensation of these sentences:

> There *was* an orange on the plate; there *were* some grapes on the plate; there *were* two apples on the plate; and there *was* a small pile of cherries on the plate.

When we shorten this to one sentence, we can only have one copy of the verb "to be" in its past tense form. So we have to choose whether it gets to be the singular "was" or plural "were".

The principle which guides the choice is probably euphony (what sounds good), and euphony dictates that we choose the form which agrees with the first element of the list. The first element is singular, and so the verb is *was*.

This is actually quite a difficult thing to explain ([snailboat](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/230/snailboat), please help!): it has to do with euphony, and with whether the items in the list behave as a group or independently, **and** it has to do with the "three is" construction.

It does not yield easily to a simplistic "one size fits all" prescriptive rule for so-called proper writing and speaking:

> Paul and Janet { was * | were } at the party.
>
> Pizza and beer { was | were } served at the party. [Was as separate items; were, as a unit; either way is okay.]
>
> There { was | were* } pizza and beer served at the party. [The "there is" construction seems to rule out regarding items as a group!]
>
> Were Bob and Mike at the party? Let me think, no. Wait, yes there { **was** | **were**? } Bob and Mike at the party!
>
> It { was | were* } Johnson and Dougherty who went inside to rob the bank; Michaelson waited outside in the getaway vehicle.

Let's look more closely at this word "there", which seems to serves as an anticipatory pronoun for a place. What place is that? The place "on the plate".  We can rewrite the sentence to eliminate "there", by relocating "on the plate" to the front. But now we can use "was" or "were"!

> <strike>There</strike> *On the plate* { was | were } an orange, some grapes, two apples and a small pile of cherries. <strike>on the plate.</strike>

This sentence can be regarded as a topicalization of the canonical sentence:

> An orange, some grapes, two apples and a small pile of cherries *were* on the plate.

There seems to be some rule that when this [topicalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topicalization) takes place, the possibility for euphonic agreement is introduced between *was* and the first element of the list.

When the word "there" is introduced, it seems to cement this need for agreement with the first list item. Once we have "there", we can move the location "on the plate" around within the sentence quite freely:

> On the plate, there was an orange, some grapes, two apples and a small pile of cherries.
>
> There was, on the plate, an orange, some grapes, two apples and a small pile of cherries.
>
> There was an orange on the plate, and some grapes, two apples and a small pile of cherries.
>
> There was an orange and some grapes on the plate, and two apples and a small pile of cherries.

It seems like "there" is not simply a placeholder for "on the plate", but a special construction.

One last note. In North America, at least, there is a widespread use of using a singular form like "there is" and "there was", without regard for the subject item or items, and this "there is" is often shortened to "there's":

> There's three apples on the table!
>
> Where? There isn't any!

This is quite widespread, used by diverse people all over; it is not a dialect that is particular to some identifiable social group or small geographic area.

There seems to be a pressure in the language to allow "there is", regardless of how many things are in the subject list and whether the first one is plural. In perhaps another hundred years, "there is" may come to be completely accepted as basically giving the situation of being. In other words, "There's three apples on the table" can be framed as "there is a situation of existence, involving three apples being on a table."

Comment: ***On the plate was an orange, some grapes, two apples and a small pile of cherries.*** That's in passive voice. The subject of the sentence is **still fruit**. Therefore, it's ***still*** were.

Comment: @JohnQPublic Passive voice requires "be + participle".  The fruits are actively being on the plate. Passive is something like: "an apple was placed on the plate by John", to which the active is "John placed the apple on the plate".

Comment: @Kaz You're right about passive voice, but you're wrong about the verb. It's an inverted sentence. I knew that ***on the plate*** was not the subject, which is why I said passive voice at first. But you're right that this is not a case of an object acting on a subject as is the case with passive constructions. As soon as I read your comment, I realized I'd made an error. But that doesn't make you correct. *On the plate* is a a prepositional phrase, so it ***cannot*** be the subject.

Comment: I also neglected to mention that *be* is not required for passive constructions. They're sometimes constructed with *get* and less often with *have*. Passive is simply O-V-S. It requires an auxiliary, but that auxiliary **does not** have to be *be*.

Comment: I want to disagree with your comment on the use of "there is" in North America. I would never say "There is two apples on the table", and I think most educated people would say that is ungrammatical. But I would say "There's two apples on the table". What is going on is ***not*** the use of "there is" for plurals, but the contraction of "there are" to "there's". A similar thing happens with "aren't". People say "aren't I?", but not "are I not?". This is because "am not" is contracted to "aren't" in some situations. The same here. If people use "there is many", they're uncontracting "there's".

Comment: @PeterShor I've been trying to explain this with to no avail. In these cases, it's always a contracted *there's* and **never** *there is*. And that's in speech only. The question was specifically about writing though.

Comment: @John Q Public: It's probably made its way from speech into writing. But I'd expect only with "there's".

Comment: @PeterShor Yes. And since educated people don't say certain things, they thereby leave uneducated people at the helm of language development. What uneducated people say now, educated ones will say a hundred years hence.

Comment: @PeterShor Again I agree (as I do with Kaz above as well). In this case, this person has an editor, and that editor is more likely than not using a specific style guide. So to me, it's a matter of formality here and *there's* would just be wrong in that light. But I do agree that it's **only** acceptable as *there's* and **not** *there is*.

Comment: Hmm, to say that "there is an orange and two apples" calls for a singular because it's a condensation of "there is an orange and there are two apples" ... By this reasoning, plurals are NEVER appropriate. "Alice and Bob are wearing green" should be "is wearing" because it's a condensation of "Alice is wearing and Bob is wearing". "Two men enter a bar" should be "enters" because it's a condensation of "one man enters a bar and then another man enters a bar". Etc.

Comment: @Jay That is simply not true; for the reasoning to be valid, *you have to have justification for the hypothesis that elision is taking place*.  Elision has rules. If you disregard that, then you can use elision as an excuse to claim that any utterance with missing words is syntactically valid.   It is not plausible that elision is taking place in "alice and bob are wearing green". It's a complete clause with no missing words.

Comment: @kaz Yes, that's my point. Are you saying that there IS a reason to see elision in "There is an orange and two apples on the table."? I don't see the relevant different between that and "Alice and Bob are ..."

Comment: @Jay Yes, I believe that it's a defensible hypothesis; certainly more so than the hypothesis that "alice and bob are wearing green" contains elision.

Answer (score -4):

"Were" is correct. There are many things on the table, and so a plural should be used.

Switch around the word order. You wouldn't say, "An orange and an apple WAS on the table." You would say, "An orange and an apple WERE on the table", because there are two things.

If elements of the subject are linked by "or", then if all the elements are singular we use the singular. "An apple or an orange WAS on each table." If all the elements are plural we use the plural. "Two apples or three oranges WERE on each table." This makes sense because if there are two singular nouns linked by OR, we are only getting one of them, so it should be singular. If there is a mix of singular and plural, the rule is that the verb matches the noun that is closest to it. "An apple or two oranges WERE on each table." "Two apples or an orange WAS on each table." "On each table was an apple or two oranges." "On each table were two oranges or an apple."

- Update *

After reading a lot of the discussion and comments, it appears to me that a lot of the discussion here centers around, not the use of the construction "there are X and Y" as opposed to "X and Y are ...", but rather to the plurality of the individual components X and Y.

That is, if the sentence was, "There are two oranges and an apple on the table", I think most of the posters here agree that "are" is correct. They would not say, "There is two oranges and an apple on the table." So the real issue is: when there is a subject consisting of two nouns joined by "and", does it take a singular verb, a plural verb, or a verb whose number is determined by the first noun?

If that's the question, every source I have ever seen says that such a compound subject takes a PLURAL verb. For example, http://www.towson.edu/ows/moduleSVAGR.htm says, "Two or more singular (or plural) subjects joined by and act as a plural compound subject and take a plural verb (singular + singular = plural)." And this makes logical sense: if there are two things, then it's plural. Whether it's two apples, or an apple and an orange, either way it's two things.

Yes, it sounds strange to some people's ears to hear "There are an orange and two apples", because "there are an orange" would be incorrect. But the sentence is NOT "There are an orange", it is "There are an orange AND two apples".

Comment: The question is about “there is/are X and Y”, which is not necessarily the same as “X and Y is/are”.

Comment: @Gilles Actually, you're wrong. They are the same. If you do not understand this, refer to Kaz's remarks regarding **there was/were** and the word **there**. You have a subject, a verb, and a prepositional phrase **with or without** *there*. ***There*** is simply a placeholder, as Kaz pointed out, in expletive constructions, so there's only one possible verb choice, and that's *were*.

Comment: Perhaps this is the point where there was confusion. Yes, in both, "There is an apple on the table" and "An apple is on the table", the subject is singular, and so the correct verb is "is". If we said, "Two apples are on the table" or "There are two apples on the table", in both cases the subject is plural, and so the correct verb is "are".