# Parsing a complex sentence

Tags: syntax, parsing

> Here **is** the past and all its inhabitants miraculously sealed as in a magic tank; all we have to do is to look and to listen and to look and soon the little figures—for they are rather under life size—will begin to move and to speak, and as they move we shall arrange them in all sorts of patterns of which they were ignorant, **for** they thought when they were alive that they could go where they liked; and as they speak we shall read into their sayings all kinds of meanings which never struck them, **for** they believed when they were alive that they said straight off whatever came into their heads. But once you are in a biography all is different. [Source](http://ebooks.adelaide.edu.au/w/woolf/virginia/w91c2/chapter20.html)

What is meant by the "for" clause here?
We arrange them in all sorts of patterns they were ignorant of because they thought they could go anywhere they liked? But it doesn't make any sense? I know overall it means we presume to know all kinds of things about the past and add interpretations of all kinds but it's far from reality. You will know it if you put yourself in a biography.

But it doesn't make sense here.

PS Is this "is" not supposed to be "are"?

Comment: *For* can mean *because* when being used as a conjunction. *Here is the past* is correct, why do you think otherwise?

Comment: Good point! I overlooked that. One of my grammar books says "In an informal style, *here's*, *there's* and *where's* are common with plural nouns."

Comment: Also related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140854/there-is-there-are-depends-on-plurality-of-the-first-list-element-or-not, and http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11986/plurality-of-verb-depending-on-plurality-of-list-elements.

Comment: "the past and all its inhabitants": _the past_ is the subject (and thus singular); _and all its inhabitants_ is really more of a subordinate, explanatory, clause (without commas or parentheses) and does not change the subject to plural. It's a stylistic thing, of somewhat unusual structure.

Answer (score 2):

- *Here is* — Woolf employs the singular because she is speaking of a single object she has in her sight: the depiction of the-past-and-its-inhabitants. She portrays Sandars’ biography of Christina Rossetti as a contrived miniature world, a “magic tank” like an aquarium. (Note the sentence a few paragraphs down: “It is as if a fish, whose unconscious gyrations we had been watching in and out of reeds, round and round rocks, suddenly dashed at the glass and broke it.”)
- *For* — These *for* clauses do not modify their respective main clauses (*we shall arrange...* and *we shall read...* but the immediately preceding subordinate clauses. Detach these clauses from the sentences in which they are embedded and they look something like this:

  > They were ignorant of these patterns, for they thought when they were alive that they could go where they liked.
  >
  > Meanings of these kinds never struck them, for they believed when they were alive that they said straight off whatever came into their heads.

Woolf implies (and will go on to say, fairly explicitly) that the ‘patterns’ and ‘meanings’ discerned by biographers and scholars and critics are abstractions from a reduced version of Rossetti’s life, abstractions which have little to do with the existence which Rossetti actually experienced, and from which her poetry grew.

Comment: @kih1930 No, "rather" means "somewhat" - but of course this may be classic British [meiosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meiosis_(figure_of_speech)).

Comment: @kih1930 Yes, exactly. Woolf is playing with a metaphor from sculpture, speaking of a reduction in physical dimensions to suggest a reduction in human complexity.

Answer (score -1):

I interpret

> Here is the past and all its inhabitants miraculously sealed as in a magic tank

as shorthand for either

> Here is the past**,** and all its inhabitants miraculously **are** sealed
>   as in a magic tank

or

> Here is the past**, with** all its inhabitants miraculously sealed
>   as in a magic tank

either one of which would (arguably) justify the use of **is**.