# there *was* a man and a woman

Tags: singular-vs-plural, subject-verb-agreement

> Once upon a time there **was** *a man and a woman* who had long, but to no avail, wished for a child.
>
> *[Rapunzel](http://www.pitt.edu/%7Edash/grimm012.html)* by the Brothers Grimm

Why it is not **were**? A man and a woman are two people, so it is plural.

The only justification I could think of is the ellipsis: there was a man and <sub>there was</sub> a woman.

Comment: We had a similar question once! http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11986/plurality-of-verb-depending-on-plurality-of-list-elements. (It looks like both are possible, and usually proximity--*was* being close to *a man*--prevails.)

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140854/there-is-there-are-depends-on-plurality-of-the-first-list-element-or-not/140863#140863

Comment: I don't know how helpful it is to point Learners to links on the ELL site. More than once I've followed a link over there to find a bewildering labrynth of "answers" and comment trails that do not provide what most Learners are looking for, namely a cogent answer. Its especially confusing to find that the checked "answer" has all or mostly negative votes. Only the most dogged Native Speaker can sift through all that verbage and come to the conclusion that there is no accepted answer, not only by ELL participants but by the multiple references they haul out in favor of their favorite usage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plurality of verb depending on plurality of list elements](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11986/plurality-of-verb-depending-on-plurality-of-list-elements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first glance, I would have said that the reason it is *was*  is because *there* is always *singular*.

However, after looking at the linked question, I have to say that it agrees with the *first* item.

- There **was** an apple and an orange on the table. `correct`
- There **were** an apple and an orange on the table. `questionable, non-standard?`
- There **was** some apples and some oranges on the table. `questionable, non-standard?`
- There **were** some apples and some oranges on the table. `correct`
- There **was** an apple and some oranges on the table. `correct`
- There **were** an apple and some oranges on the table. `questionable, non-standard?`
- There **was** some apples and an orange on the table. `incorrect, maybe non-standard?`
- There **were** some apples and an orange on the table. `correct`

The reason that those cases of "there was" seems questionable and not *entirely* ungrammatical is because *there* is singular.

Comment: I agree with all cases, except for this one: *There were an apple and some oranges on the table.* I think I would consider it *possibly* correct (questionable is okay, imo, but perhaps not downright *incorrect*).