# Is or are. What to use here?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

- The guitar **is** not the same thing as the violin

What if I say this sentence this way:

- The guitar and the violin **are** not the same thing.

Or should it be:

- The guitar and the violin **is** not the same thing.

Comment: "Are". The subject is plural

Comment: Remember your capital letters. The first letter of each sentence and the word "I" should be capitalised.

Comment: This question may have answers that also answer your question:  https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/11986/

Answer (score 1):

You have two subjects (plural) so you need to use a plural verb (**are** in your case).

- The guitar and violin are different instruments.

You can use a singular verb if you refer to two subjects as a union, as a whole or something that represents a single thing. However, you should be careful and use it wisely in terms of logic:

- A guitar and an e-bow is a great combination in art rock.

Comment: But first one's correct. The guitar is not the same as the violin. But both sentences are same although. right?

Comment: @user62016 In the first sentence you have one subject.

Comment: But they mean the same.  Dont they?

Comment: @user62016 grammatically, yes. But logically one might say they aren't. However, I can't see how they can differ.

Comment: i edited the question. is it still okay?

Comment: what about now? @SovereignSun

Comment: I wanna ask one more question. Can i turn it to a chat?

Comment: @user62016 — if it's related to this topic, you should create a chat room because this comment section is not for discussion; comments are ephemeral and some comments are often overlooked when one or more comments are upvoted. If it's not related to this question, it's better to ask a new question. (It's encouraged do some research before asking a new question and don't forget to provide context.)