# "There he and his friends come." or "There come he and his friends."

Tags: existentials

Let me start with basic pattern that is followed;

> 1. When the subject/topic is a pronoun only: *There he comes.*
> 2. When the subject/topic is not a pronoun: *There come his friends.*

How about the merger of both a pronoun and another pronoun and/or something else?

For example;

> 1. There he and his friends come.
> 2. There come he and his friends.
> 3. There his friends and he come.
> 4. There come his friends and he.
> 5. There you and he come.
> 6. There come you and he.
> 7. There he and Muhammad come.
> 8. There come he and Muhammad.
> 9. There Muhammad and he come.
> 10. There come Muhammad and he.

With that many possibilities mentioned above, I wanna know if any or all are correct.

P.S. What rules follow, if any!? ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> There he comes.
>
> There come his friends.

are idiomatic enough that while gramatically there's nothing wrong with reversing the order, it would sound completely alien to do so.

Since you combine the two, 'pronoun and something else', the latter case becomes our thing.

The most common and best variant would be:

> **There come his friends and he**.

When mentioning a list of people, you put the single pronoun, 'I', 'he' etc at the end (it's a style/etiquette thing, not actually grammar). And that simultaneously closes the can of worms about choosing whether to use 'come' or 'comes' here. (the can of worms for a reference: [1](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/11986/plurality-of-verb-depending-on-plurality-of-list-elements) [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/140854/there-is-there-are-depends-on-plurality-of-the-first-list-element-or-not) ) - the first element of the list is plural, so we use the plural form of the verb without doubt.

You might encounter variants:

> There come his friends and him.

Actually grammatically incorrect but common enough it may be eventually accepted into grammar. (If you strip the rest of the list, the subject should match with the verb. "There comes him" is obviously wrong.)

> There comes he with his friends.

This bundles the group into a singular entity, so it becomes singular.

And finally:

> There come[s] Muhammad and he.

And here we have the aforementioned problem with plurality. Properly grammatically correct is 'There come Muhammad and he' but it sounds slightly unnatural so you might find 'There comes Muhammad and he' as well. 'There come he and Muhammad' sounds totally unnatural despite being formally grammatically correct. It's a mess. Just bundle them with 'with' to avoid the headache.

> Here comes Muhammad with him

or

> Here he comes with Muhammad.

Comment: "There come you and he." would better be like "There you come with him.", right?

Comment: Right. And as I look at "There come you and he" it's grammatically correct but stylistically a monster.