# Is "his wife and he" incorrect?

Tags: grammar, word-order

I couldn't find any gramar rule that  says "* and he" is incorrect.

However, I [found out](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/193107/there-he-and-his-friends-come-or-there-come-he-and-his-friends) that "he and *" is more common/idiomatic.

Are constructions like "his wife and he" or "her friends and she" incorrect/uncommon? Why or why not?

Example sentence: "His wife and he went to Hawaii last week."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no rule against it. It's much more common to say "he and his wife", "she and her friends", etc. But switching the order is perfectly correct.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=he+and+his+wife%2Chis+wife+and+he&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Che%20and%20his%20wife%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chis%20wife%20and%20he%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Che%20and%20his%20wife%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chis%20wife%20and%20he%3B%2Cc0

In general I'd say to use the more conventional order. But if you have some reason to reverse it -- emphasis, parallel with another sentence, whatever -- it's perfectly fine.

Comment: You should know about false positives in Ngrams. It cannot be cited without checking that the instances actually include the phrase unadulterated. For example: … *And the miller awoke, and found* **not his wife ; and he went** *into the mill* … **2** … *he was unduly pessimistic about his relationship with **his wife, and he agrees** that this is certainly a pattern for him*… **3** … *the man who worked as foreman in the bicycle factory killed* ***his wife and he is now*** *in the courts* … **4**  … *And the men of the place **asked him of his wife**; **and he said***, *She is my sister*:…

Comment: @Mari-LouA Fair enough. Is it your position that "his wife and he" is wrong? Or just the the ngram is misleading?

Comment: I would say native speakers never use that order. It's confusing it sounds like a same sex marriage, nothing wrong with that but I had to read the statement twice before I realised the female spouse headed the phrase.